# Implementing multi-threading in workflows

Tags: multithreading, workflow-foundation-4

I'm aware a single workflow instance run in a single thread at a time. I've a workflow with two receive activities inside a pick activity. Message correlation is implemented to make sure the requests to both the activities should be routed to the same instance.

In the first receive branch I've a parallel activity with a delay activity in one branch. The parallel activity will complete either the delay is over or a flag is set to true.

When the parallel activity is waiting for the condition to meet how I can receive calls from the second receive activity? because the flag will be set to true only through through it's branch. I'm waiting for your suggestions or ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out my blog [The Workflow Parallel Activity and Task Parallelism](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/06/28/the-workflow-parallel-activity-and-task-parallelism.aspx)  This will help you understand how WF works

Comment: Thanks Ron. Good posts from you.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here.

If you have a Pick with 2 branched and both branches contain a Receive it will continue after you receive either of the 2 messages the 2 Receive activities are waiting for. The other will be canceled and not receive anything. The fact that one Receive is in a Parallel will not make a difference here. So unless this is on a loop you will not receive more than one WCF message in your workflow.

Comment: There is a while loop and the workflow instance waits still it get all the messages. I'm getting the feeling that parallel programming is very hard in WF 4.0 and I can't able to design a simple multi-threaded workflow. May be I'm not approaching the problem in the right direction.

Comment: As you correctly pointed out in your question there is no multi threaded execution in workflow. There is is however queuing as everything is scheduled asynchronously. So is both WCF requests arrive at almost the same time the first will be processed and the second will be queued and processed if the workflow loops back to the same Pick with the receive activity.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Is it possible to cancel the delay activity when a new request arrives at the second receive branch so still the things goes in a single thread. Now what's happening is when the first receive branch got struck up by the delay activity I can't able to receive requests through the second branch they are queued as you said but once the delay is over the queued requests are getting processed. I just want to cancel the delay and process the requests.

Comment: Yes using the CompletionCondition. Although I have to add that most people use a Pick with three branches, 2 with a Receive in the trigger and a third with a Delay. That way cancellation is automatically done.